# JPA Inheritance with Two Abstract Class

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have a question about inheritance in JPA, is it possible to do this Hierarchy using JOINED strategy?

Here my code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING,  length = 4)
public abstract class Person implements Serializable {
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="EMPL")
public abstract class Employee extends Person implements Serializable{
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CLIENT")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="CLIE")
public class Client extends Person implements Serializable{
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TEACHER")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="TEAC")
public class Teacher extends Employee implements Serializable{
...
}
```

After the above hierarchy, I tried to make a query using JPQL, this is the query:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="FICHA_EVALUACION")
public class SheetEvaluation implements Serializable{
    @OneToOne
    private Teacher teacher;
}
```

This code run from a main

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT f FROM SheetEvaluation f, Teacher teac,  Employee emp, Person per WHERE f.teacher.id = teac.id and teac.id = emp.id and emp.id =  per.id");

List<SheetEvaluation> sheetEvaluations =  query.getResultList();



for (SheetEvaluation sheetEvaluation : sheetEvaluations ) {
     System.out.println(" Teacher Name= " + sheetEvaluation .getTeacher().getName());

}
```

when I run the query throws me the following error

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'employee1_.DTYPE' in 'field list'

Please if you have any idea about the type of error obtained much I appreciate your support.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I am no hibernate guru, but I think You can't have `@DiscriminatorColumn` when you are using table-per-class, it is only required whne you have single class for all the inhereted classes and want to discriminate between them.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050608/jpa-inheritance-using-single-table-discriminator-value-doesnt-match-class) for single table join.

In you current join, It will create table for all the classe and will have person fk.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Person implements Serializable {
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable{
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="CLIENT")
public class Client extends Person implements Serializable{
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TEACHER")
public class Teacher extends Employee implements Serializable{
...
}
```